# Crear archivo log en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy implementando un log en mi programa de Python usando la función `file.write` de Python, de la siguiente manera:

```
log = open("src\log.txt", "a+")

    def file_log(self,datos):
        self.log.write(datos)
```

Pero leyendo en manuales de Python he descubierto el modulo `logging`. Según he visto el funcionamiento usando `logger.warning` es parecido, por eso me ha surgido la duda de si hay uno que sea mas recomendable que el otro y por que.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuáles dos estás comparando? ¿Tu sistema con el módulo `logging`? Este último es infinitamente más complejo y versátil, permitiéndote catalogar los mensajes de log en warnings, errores, debug, info... modificar qué nivel de log quieres hacer, a qué ficheros va la salida (si va a alguno, o a pantalla), formatear los mensajes de log añadiendo timestamps, tipos de mensaje, activar o desactivar el logging, tener varios loggers (para diferentes submódulos) etc.

Comment: El problema de logging es precisamente todo lo que abarca, lo que le hace difícil de usar. Hay alternativas más sencillas, como el paquete logme  o loguru (que incluyen además diferentes colores según el tipo de mensaje, cuando el log va a pantalla), con el inconveniente de que no forma parte de la biblioteca estándar, y por tanto es otra dependencia a instalar.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios @abulafia. Indagaré mas en profundidad sobre las posibilidades que ofrece.